# gorm domain class shared property

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have 4 classes

```groovy
class Process {
    String status

}

class Request {
    String status = "incomplete"

    belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}

class Response {
    String status = "incomplete"

    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}

class Confirmation {
   String status = "incomplete"

   static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}
```

Then the status of Request, Response or Confirmation will be updated.

How can I achieve to autoupdate Process.status with the status of the last updated of the other three classes ?

Is there a particular grails-way to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0):

Without all the details on how your domains are mapped - specifically what the relationship from Process to Request, Response and Confirmation - I'll assume that you have access to Process from the other domains.

With that assumption, you can use [GORM Events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping) to achieve an update to `Process.status` on an `afterUpdate` event in the other domains.

For example, in Request, Response and Confirmation, you can define something like:

```
def afterUpdate() {
  .. //get Process some how
  process.status = this.status
}
```